# Instrumentation testing in compose in a firebase app

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I'm trying to create tests in compose and I'm always getting the following error:

> Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process X. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I've tried to simplify the most the code of the test:

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

@Test
fun test() {

    composeTestRule.setContent {
        Text("Whatever")
    }
}
```

but still getting that error.

I've tried with uiThreadTestRule:

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

@get:Rule
var uiThreadTestRule: UiThreadTestRule = UiThreadTestRule()

@Test
fun test() {
    uiThreadTestRule.runOnUiThread {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
    }

    composeTestRule.setContent {
        Text("Whatever")
    }
}
```

and also with the same composeTestRule.runOnUiThread:

```kotlin
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

@Test
fun test() {
    composeTestRule.runOnUiThread {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
    }

    composeTestRule.setContent {
        Text("Whatever")
    }
}
```

How can that `FirebaseApp is not initialized` error be fixed so that the composables of this app can be tested?

**Update**

It seems to be something about the createComposeRule() cause the following test:

```
@get:Rule
val composeTestRule: ComposeContentTestRule = createComposeRule()

@Test
fun test() {
    assertEquals(2, 1 + 1)
}
```

also fails and it passes if I remove the rule.
I don't need the firebase dependency in the tests if it's possible to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this into the gradle file of that module to exclude the firebase dependency:

```
configurations {
    androidTestImplementation {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-perf'
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone know why this is required? :(.

Comment: because without excluding this in tests the firebase library checks that the app should invoke `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context)` and you probably don't want to run that on tests and just use the test libraries that create a dummy app for you and sometimes even a dummy activity. That could be also avoidable if you can isolate the firebase dependency from the module you are testing but that wasn't my case (due to legacy code in that app).

Answer (score -1):

In Kotlin DSL you can set

```
configurations {

    this.androidTestImplementation {

        this.exclude("com.google.firebase", "firebase-perf")
    }
}
```